# Energy/entropy in transport of molecules across cell membranes

Tags: energy, entropy, work, biophysics

I'm asking a "Maxwell's Demon" question.  I've read statements that sorting molecules and sending them to one side or the other of a barrier requires work, but none of these statements have explained what kind of work.  Given the fundamental definition of work as $Fdx$, what force is involved?

The biological context of my question is the movement of glucose through a cell membrane, **against** its concentration gradient, using energy from the co-transport of sodium ions into the cell **with** the Na+ concentration gradient (the latter process providing energy via ATP-->ADP). Thanks in advance for enlightening me!

Comment: a desalination plant requires a lot of work to push the membranes

Comment: If I do not remember wrong (I forgot to take my pill) a maxwell demon has to record the position of the particle and the work required to do that was dissipated as heat, or perhaps the reverse. In any case, maxwell demons that obey the laws of physics cannot violate the second law.

Comment: John Forkosh, I disagree with your math.  Acceleration is dv/dt, not dp/dt.  Force alone is dp/dt.  You have not included a "dx" term, where dW = Fdx, so the equations you gave don't actually add up to work done.  Unquestionably though, work is done bringing an ion through the cell membrane, since the distance moved is the thickness of the membrane.  The nature of the force, though, hangs me up.  Ions clearly experience electrostatic force.  But suppose it's a non-polar uncharged species?

Answer (score 1):

I found what I think is an answer to my question elsewhere in the stackexchange, in a discussion of entropy and energy by Carl Brannen, here <https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1272/carl-brannen>
Evidently there is more to the equation relating internal energy, entropy and work than is usually shown in textbooks. I don't know how to type equations on this site so I'll have to fudge it a bit with words, but Brannen points out that, besides the familiar TdS and -PdV terms for dU, there is also a term (mu)dM, where (mu) is the chemical activity and dM is the incremental change in mass.  In the case of ion transport across a cell membrane, if I define the system as being only the cell, its membrane, and the ions that move through it, there is clearly a change in mass within the system.  delta M > 0.  And the ions undergoing transport, as well as the protein channel through which they move, being chemicals, have chemical activity.  At any rate, the point is that internal energy can be changed in ways that do not involve either entropy or PV work.